# Listview C# to html

Tags: c#, html, listview

I have a listview in my C# application. Now I want the values of the listview in an HTML file with `text.Replace()` method. I am trying to get the values of my listview in a HTML page.

The code:

```
<h5>"+ listView1.Items.ToString() +"</h5>");
```

But I am not getting the result that I want. I've got not the values

[image: Image of the error]

Could you guys help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using ToString() on the collection object. You are assuming this will iterate all the objects in the collection and give you a concatenated string of the results. This is not what toString() does.

ToString() on a class will pass you back a string value which is whatever the class has been programmed as being most appropriate. In the .net framework almost all Collections (arrays, lists, etc) dont have a ToString() override so call the base class (object) and execute its ToString() method. The ToString() method of the base object class returns the name of the class - not its content or any other property.

To get the results you want you need to write a loop around your collection object and build the HTML one item at a time. This example code shows the way forwards (but I wouldn't recommend this particular repeated string concatenation in live application; at the very least I would recommend using the StringBuilder class - but it serves to illustrate the method).

```
string html = "<h5>";
foreach(string item in listView1.Items)
{
    html += item;
} 
html += "</h5>";
```